# Stop further code process anytime

Tags: vb.net

How to break entire process at any point of code process. Let's say i have code process which is going as follows:

```
MethodA: (classX)
Dim _repRunner As New ReportRunner()
_repRunner.Run

Process flow:
(start process) class(X)MethodA->class(f)MethodB->class(g)MethodC->class(g)MetodC->class(h)MethodD->class(i)MethodE->class(i)MethodF->(classX)MethodA (end proceess)
```

Let's assume within MethodC i want to break further process. I don't want to always make all functions to return e.g Boolean before accessing next one. Is there any way to breake root object call and return?

Comment: You need to structure your code differently, and utilize conditional blocks or an alternative would be throw an exception inside a try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "break."  If you mean "stop processing in response to some event" then we need to identify how that event is exposed to your code.

Let's just assume for now that a "break" event sets a variable called `Globals.BreakRequested`.  Then you just need to modify your code like this:

```
class f
{
    public bool MethodB()
    {
        bool result = DoSomething();
        if (Globals.BreakRequested) return result;
        var next = new g();
        return next.MethodC(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: by break i mean to stop going further (i can make e.g some log) and stop executing next methods... Go back to root method (MethodA)

Comment: I understand, but that isn't very specific.  Code will stop executing whenever you use the `return` keyword.  I am thinking you want something more specific than that.

Comment: yes but return will only escape from current scope.

Comment: Right.  The calling method would have to `return` as well, and so on down the stack until you get to where you want to go.

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirements.  How is a "break" initiated?  How does your code know when a break is needed?

Comment: Have one very and bit complicated code which process files comming from diffrent servers. Files are excel files. There are collection/parser/loader parts. On the collection parser part if at least one thing goes wrong e.g columns not match or data missing have to break execution for instance raise emails to technicals and stop code for further process.

Comment: Oh. So why not just [throw an exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty79csek.aspx)?